# Development of a neural network with images and numbers as inputs, simultaniously

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I have 1000 grayscale images and corresponding to every  (x,y) position of 5 particles for 1000 iteration. So, basically, 1000 images and a list of numbers as
1          2      3         4       5
x01,y01  x02,y02  x03,y03  x04,y04  x05,y05

```
     x11,y11  x12,y12  x13,y13  x14,y14  x15,y15

       .        .         .        .       .

       .        .         .        .       .
     
       .        .         .        .       .
```

How to build a Neural network that takes images and the numbers as input and when an test image put as input, it gives the coordinates (x,y) as output?

Lets separate 700 data as training and 300 as testing.

Comment: Your question is far too broad for Stack Overflow as you seem to be asking someone to complete your entire project for you. You need to attempt to solve it yourself and, if you have specific problems, come back and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a way..... Just use the Functional API (FAPI) in Keras instead of sequential API. FAPI is capable of handling different kinds of inputs simultaneously.